# IS $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\beta\cdot g(x)}g(x)^{\alpha-1}={\Gamma(\alpha)\over \beta^\alpha}\ \ ?$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, gamma-function

Is the following statement true:

> Let $g(x)$ be some non-negative continuous function of $x$.We know $$\int_{0}^\infty e^{-\beta x}x^{\alpha-1}dx={\Gamma(\alpha)\over \beta^\alpha}$$
>
> IS $$\int_{0}^\infty e^{-\beta\cdot g(x)}g(x)^{\alpha-1}dx={\Gamma(\alpha)\over \beta^\alpha}\ \ ?$$

Comment: Let $g(x)=0{}$.

Comment: @SimpleArt I added something to my question . Please check.

Comment: The first equation is already false. The integration should run from $0$ to $\infty$, not $-\infty$ to $\infty$.

Comment: @ByronSchmuland Thanks.

Comment: Now if $g(x)=|x|$, there was honestly no point in the substitution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are most likely thinking of the substitution $x=g(u),\ dx=g'(u)du$ where

$g(u)\to\infty,u\to\infty$

$g(u)\to0,u\to0$

$g(u)$ is bijective.

Putting in the substitution, we would get

$$\int_0^\infty e^{-\beta x}x^{\alpha-1}dx=\int_0^\infty g'(u)e^{-\beta g(u)}g(u)^{\alpha-1}du$$

Comment: Does this mean any $g(u)$ with $g(u)\to\infty$ as $u\to\infty$ and $g(u)\to\-infty$ as $u\to-\infty$ will make the second statement correct?

Comment: @Qwerty Hinges on if the first integral was correct to begin with.  It's just standard substitution assuming $g(u)$ is bijective.

Comment: I have edited my question(changed limits) to make equations correct. Can you please edit your answer to siut my needs?

Comment: @Qwerty Sure.  And note that regular substitution works regardless of the bounds with bijective functions and all that.